# i am facing an error while loading snowpipe into snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

Pipe Notifications bind failure "Cross cloud integration is not supported for pipe creation in AZURE using a stage in AWS."
auto_ingest=true; //couldn't compile, facing the above error.

i couldn't find any possible solutions to try

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake Snowpipe on Azure can only ingest from Azure cloud storage services. See [Snowpipe Supported Cloud Storage Services](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html#supported-cloud-storage-services) for details.

Comment: Dave this no longer looks to be the case https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-cloud-platforms#data-loading `Snowflake supports loading data from files staged in any of the following locations, regardless of the cloud platform for your Snowflake account`

Comment: Yay, Snowflake. Always new features and capabilities coming from the Snow boffins.

Comment: Snowpipe now supports cross cloud ingestion.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro#supported-cloud-storage-services